# App crashes on scrolling recyclerview android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have implemented RecyclerView in my fragment which shows three different types of data. It is displayed correctly when launched but after scrolling two items app crashes. Below is the error log from logact along with my build.gradle:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId 'com.app.yaw'
    minSdkVersion 16
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true

}
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile ('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.8.0'){
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
}
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
compile 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.+'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:2.0.0@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
}
```

Error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                       Process: com.app.yaw, PID: 4842
                                                       java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method getMatrix(Landroid/view/View;)Landroid/graphics/Matrix; in class Landroid/support/v4/view/ViewCompat; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat' appears in /data/data/com.app.yaw/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.support-support-v4-23.1.1_f0d40c0c98a4f0392163431bacae3584a7d8e5f6-classes.dex)
                                                           at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.getTransformedBoundingBox(RecyclerView.java:8100)
                                                           at android.support.v7.widget.OrientationHelper$2.getTransformedEndWithDecoration(OrientationHelper.java:402)
                                                           at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.recycleViewsFromStart(LinearLayoutManager.java:1275)
                                                           at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.recycleByLayoutState(LinearLayoutManager.java:1347)
                                                           at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1371)
                                                           at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.scrollBy(LinearLayoutManager.java:1193)
                                                           at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.scrollVerticallyBy(LinearLayoutManager.java:1043)
                                                           at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.scrollByInternal(RecyclerView.java:1596)
                                                           at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onTouchEvent(RecyclerView.java:2704)
                                                           at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:8287)
                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2318)
                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2050)
                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2324)
                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2064)
                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2324)
                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2064)
                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2324)
                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2064)
                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2324)
                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2064)
                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2324)
                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2064)
                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2324)
                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2064)
                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2324)
                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2064)
                                                           at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2327)
                                                           at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1705)
                                                           at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2797)
                                                           at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2288)
                                                           at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:8477)
                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4281)
                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4147)
                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3652)
                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3705)
                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3671)
                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3781)
                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3679)
                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3838)
                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3652)
                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3705)
                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3671)
                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3679)
                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3652)
                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5961)
                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEve
```

Comment: On which android version do you run app?

Comment: You should provide your code!

Comment: edited now... build.gradle code is added

Answer (score 1):

I was suffering the same problem, I solved mine by changing the dependencies in Project/gradle/build.gradle file.
For me the problem was that the appcompat version was lower than the recycler views. I simply changed the recyclers version to match the appcompat.[Screen shot of what and where](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lzz5x.png)

Hope this helps
Tommy